# the courtesy of explaining himself

Tags: ellipsis

Can one say

a. I am giving him the courtesy of explaining himself.

instead of

b. I am giving him the courtesy of allowing him to explain himself.

?

Many thanks

Comment: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/do-somebody-the-courtesy-of-doing-something

Answer (score 1):

Context is missing; normally the one who is explaining themselves is "doing the courtesy". In your example it is not quite clear, perhaps you found your spouse with another lover and rather than simply leaving them, you could be said to be giving them the courtesy, by asking for an explanation/excuse (whereas you could legitimately just leave them forever without asking). Thus it is implied that the other person is not really due your time, to be allowed to explain themselves. Therefore 1 is certainly wrong and 2 is correct.

Comment: Try to avoid answering questions that don't explain themselves. I also disagree with your conclusions.

Comment: Not sure what you are disagreeing with exactly. My answer explains the context in which you would give some the courtesy and that in which they would give you the courtesy, which is not strictly necessary if we assume that the question is correct.

Comment: I see one as merely an ellipsis of the other, nothing to do with who gives who permission to do anything.

Comment: Thank you both. I think you disagree about the meaning of (a). I read it the same way Thelawnet does. If I go out of my way to allow someone to explain himself, can I use (a)? That is the question.